# Using multiple COM objects that have the same methods/events/everything but reside in different namespaces in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I have a pair of COM objects in two different places that follow the exact same interface (except for namespace, so `nsA.ICOMObject` looks the same as `nsB.ICOMObject` with the exception that `nsA` is replaced by `nsB` all over the place).

Which of the objects I will be using is decided on application startup and can be held easily enough. The issue that I have is how to do all of this without duplication. I know that for method calls I can do it simply with a `dynamic` object but that still leaves me an issue with event handling.

Currently I would do:

```cs
if (useObjectA)
{
    theCOMObject.eventToHandle += new nsA.eventHandler(method);
}
else
{
    theCOMObject.eventToHandle += new nsB.eventHandler(method);
}
```

all over the place and for just a namespace change this seems a little silly.

Am I right that there is an easier way to do this and what is it? There are literally hundreds of methods/properties/events on these objects so creating an object that takes all the pain away would be very hard work.

Many Thanks

Gareth

Comment: Isn't that exactly what an interface is for? when you state **the exact same interface** isn't that just going to be `ICOMObject.eventToHandle`?

Comment: I agree, the issue is that the interfaces are the same except for they reside in different namespaces and contain references to classes in their respective namespaces that are the same.

Comment: So the interfaces are not the same at all.  This can't get better until you go back to the COM object implementation itself and make them use the exact same interface declaration.  Not only does that allow you to treat them the same in your program, it is also a hard guarantee that these interfaces will *forever* be the same.  If you didn't create these COM objects then the weapon of choice is a telephone.

Comment: @HansPassant I wish I were working in a nice dynamic language here, then it would all work nicely for me. Given that we have dynamic in C#4 is there really no nice way of doing this? Seems like a massive issue to me if that's the case.

Comment: ridecar2. The issue is that you're asking for duck Typing, there's no guarantee that the interfaces support the same methods with the same signatures. Are you restricted by framework? [as dynamic would probably work in this case.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278078/what-is-interface-duck-typing).

Comment: Could the person who downvoted please comment as to why the downvote so that I may ask better questions (or ask questions better) in future?

Comment: Do `nsA.ICOMObject` an `nsB.ICOMObject` still deal with the same COM object (same CLSID?)

Comment: Unfortunately they do not, the COM objects are in different files too.