# two class with common methods and properties

Tags: c#, .net, class, dynamic, duck-typing

I have two classes.

Class A:

```
class A() {
    public void QQ() {}
    public void WW() {}
}
```

And Class B:

```
class B() {
    public void QQ() {}
    public void WW() {}
}
```

They don't share the same interface or abstract class.
A and B have two distinct hierarcy and I can't change that at the moment.

I want to write  a single procedute that works for A and B and use QQ and WW methods.

Can I do that? Can you suggest any document I can study?

Tanks

Comment: you can use a delegate

Comment: it's very similar to dynamic type

Comment: "They don't share the same interface" - yes, currently there is no `interface` that they both implement. However, they clearly have some part of their public surface in common. So define an interface `ICanQQAndWW`, and have them both implement it. Why search for an ugly hack when there's already an obvious clean way to do it?

Comment: Thank you all! I learned something new and different approaches

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

You can use dynamics

```
void Foo(dynamic dy)
{
    dy.QQ();
}
```

You can also use reflection. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21280650/3970411))

```
public static void CallQQ(object o)
{
    var qq = o.GetType().GetMethod("QQ");
    if (qq != null)
        qq.Invoke(o, new object[] { });
    else
        throw new InvalidOperationException("method not found");
}
```

Comment: This ignores the fact that the object dy may not have a QQ method, which would cause a runtime error.

Comment: @Domysee I think this is better than hiding that fact in your approach

Comment: @IvanStoev what do you mean? There is always the possibility to throw an exception if no type applies.

Comment: Dear Downvoter. Care to comment?

Comment: @Domysee I mean that your method does nothing if you don't recognize the passed object type, thus hiding that fact from the caller. It should really throw exception, which will make it similar to this approach, but not so flexible. This answer is definitely better. +1

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the explanation. I agree with you, this answer is more flexible and better adapts to change.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the object is of the specific type, then cast it and invoke its method:

```
void InvokeQQ(object o){
    if(o is A)
        (o as A).QQ();
    if(o is B)
        (o as B).QQ();
}
```

In C#6 you can simplify this to

```
void InvokeQQ(object o){
    (o as A)?.QQ();
    (o as B)?.QQ();
}
```

Comment: This is not a single method. This is combination of two method. You can combine all methods in world in to one method using this approach.

Comment: in c#6 it can be simplified to `(o as A)?.QQ();`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: What if we have 500 class with same `QQ()` method?

Comment: this approach has a nice syntax

Comment: @dotctor I agree with you that if there many classes with that method, using dynamic is better (less work). However, I dont think that we should sacrifice type safety if there are just 2 classes with these methods.

Comment: Why do you think that using object is type safe but using dynamic is not?

Comment: @dotctor Well, after the cast we have the correct type again. But you have a point there.

Answer (score -1):

Cant you just make a parent class and put these methods in it and then let A and B inherit from that class?

Comment: *"A and B have two distinct hierarcy and I can't change that at the moment."*

Comment: can you explain your question in a little more detail? like do you want both of these methods to be called at the same time from a certain method in Main or somewhere?

Comment: I have 2 classes with equal methods. The first is a production class and the latter is a test environment class.

It's absurd I know.

I have to write a code that works both in production and in test environment and I have to use those classes.