# Dynamic variable Compilation

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
dynamic d = "hello";
Console.WriteLine (d.ToUpper()); // HELLO
Console.WriteLine (d.Foo()); // Compiles OK but gives runtime error
```

I'm reading a book an stumbled in this section, in the third line it only throws error during runtime but it will compile even though `Foo` method doesn't exist.

Why not check it in compile time rather than in runtime?

Edit: 
What is the significance, and when can I use this concept?

Comment: You can mark it as duplicate, my only goal in this post is to get input from experienced programmers, you cannot find it all in a book or even in some posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dynamic`, you are instructing the compiler to ignore it and let the runtime handle it. This is super helpful when dealing with COM and other interfaces that the compiler doesn't know about.

If you want implicit types use `var` instead. The compiler will infer the type and keep it strongly typed.

Comment: when can I use this technique? or the proper way of using it?

Comment: @Desperado, the book you are reading should have that explanation of proper use as well. Else, search in SO, there are ample similar question present.

Comment: @Rahul yes I read it, but not all concepts and techniques are present. We cannot argue that when we deal with experienced programmers

Comment: thanks bro! This is helpful even if I lost some of my reputations T.T moderators sigh

Comment: Daniel, No complain and your answer is far more correct and I did upvoted but still fill this answer shouldn't have been given keeping in mind that there are already duplicate question present.

Comment: @Rahul the question had morphed since it was originally posted.

Comment: @DanielA.White I agree, my question is "Why not check it in compile time rather than in runtime?" and this is unique with the duplicated suggestions

Answer (score 4):

The `dynamic`-keyword causes this behaviour which is intended. When making a variable `dynamic` you can do *everything* with it making it not compile-time-safe. So by making it `dynamic` you completely bypass the compiletime-types - that´s why you should take care when using it.

Checking the members at runtime is the whole point of `dynamic` though - why should it exist otherwise?

I assume you intentionally wanted the `var`-keyword which *gives* you compiletime-safety. Have a look at [this point for the difference on both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961581/whats-the-difference-between-dynamicc-4-and-var). As to the *when* to use the keyword have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674906/when-should-one-use-dynamic-keyword-in-c-sharp-4-0).

Comment: when can I use this technique? or the proper way of using it?

Comment: Usually not at all, there are a only a dew circumstances you should use it. Anyway I won´t care to much for it as long as you don´t have to *eplicitly*.

Comment: thanks bro! This is helpful even if I lost some of my reputations T.T moderators sigh

Comment: Now by accepting an answer you got it back :), so you got some knowledge and lost nothing... sounds like a positive topic.

Comment: I thought my reputation is back, I checked it immediately lol Sorry I'm not a native english speaker